# Custom ListView disappear on rotation in Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

The problem is that I have a custom ListView with its own adapter. But when I change the screen orientation the element disappears. I made some research and tried to use `onConfigurationChanged` but it doesn't work for me. Here's code:

I can't put `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in my AndroidManifest.xml, because it's a fragment, so I put it in dataload_tab4.xml .

Please, don't focus on another code. Main ListView init is in `InitView()`.

**Tab4.java (I have many tabs :D)**

```
public class Tab4 extends Fragment {

    private Button btnCertAdd, btnCertDel;
    private ArrayList CertNames = new ArrayList(), CertNumbers= new ArrayList(), CertIssueDates= new ArrayList(), CertExpireDates= new ArrayList();
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private ListView lv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dataload_tab4, null);
        InitView(view);
        frameLayout.addView(view);
        return frameLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        frameLayout. removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dataload_tab4, null);
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, CertNames, CertNumbers, CertIssueDates, CertExpireDates);

        lv = view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(listViewAdapter); // null - изначально ничего нет

        frameLayout.addView(view);
    }


    private void InitView(View view)
    {
       btnCertAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnaddcert);
       btnCertDel = view.findViewById(R.id.btndelcert);

       listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, CertNames, CertNumbers, CertIssueDates, CertExpireDates);

       lv = view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
       lv.setAdapter(listViewAdapter); // null - изначально ничего нет  
    }


    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Just to visualize the problem. 
Here's a screen when it loads; I add some data (cut it from the code)

[image]

And here I change orientation. All data disappear.
[image]

Comment: You should consider to integrating ViewModel from the Android Architecture Components. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations. See here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Comment: @Sini, could you please show an example of using them? I've checked some videos, but it's too complicated for me, i am new to Android programming (i'm just 16 yrs old). Could you please tell me what i have to change in my code, to avoid this bug, and put this as an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the reason of bad rating? There's no such theme at SOF, why devote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did some research and found an answer by myself.

I found no *normal* ways to avoid data loss, but we still can save it in `savedInstanceState`.

So, we need to add this to our Fragment Activity, where we want data to be saved.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Here, you have to put some data in outState bundle, look below for an example
    }
```

And here's an example

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        int i = 0;
        for (SailorExperience se:ExpsInfo) {
            outState.putString(EXPINFO_KEY + String.valueOf(i) ,se.toString());
            i++;
        }
        outState.putInt(savedInstanceExpCount_key, i);

        i = 0;
        for(String s:busyIDs){
            outState.putString(BUSYIDS_KEY + String.valueOf(i),s);
            i++;
        }
        outState.putInt(savedInstanceBusyIdsCount_key, i);
    }
```

**`ExpsInfo`** is an ArrayList of my custom class,

**`busyIds`** is an ArrayList of String

In my case, i need to save **ArrayList**, so i am putting every single data of this **ArrayList** in an single `.putString`of `outState` **Bundle**. Also I save size of this **ArrayList** as another integer value.

**After all of manipulation's, you need to load all data again**

So you need to check if `savedInstanceState`**is not `null`**. If it's not null, then there's some data which you've saved. **Don't try to pass** some private **variables** (**they will not be marked as initialized**, idk how it works with public).
As an example, you need to add this code in your **`onCreateView()`** method:

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            for(int i = 0; i<savedInstanceState.getInt(savedInstanceExpCount_key); i++){
                ExpsInfo.add(new SailorExperience(savedInstanceState.getString(EXPINFO_KEY + String.valueOf(i))));
            }
            for(int i=0; i<savedInstanceState.getInt(savedInstanceBusyIdsCount_key);i++){
                busyIDs.add(savedInstanceState.getString(BUSYIDS_KEY + String.valueOf(i)));
            }
        }
```

**I'm doing this part of code before main UI load.**

If i helped to solve your problem, make sure you left a +rep. ^_^